# Is there a less fantastically kludgy way to do one-off highlights in Vim?

Tags: vim

**i. The Problem**

My goal is something like the following:

I have a line of text like

```
Who left the dead mouse in the fridge?
```

and I want to highlight the first `the` in green, just this one occurrence. That is, I don't want to `syn match ThisMagicWord "\<the\>"` or anything that will overzealously highlight other `the`s.

There is one other requirement, which is that if the user edits the other text on the line, say to

```
Who on earth left the delicious dead mouse in the fridge?
```

the highlighting will track with the word `the`, so long as the user doesn't edit that one particular word.

**ii. The Kludge**

Now, I have a solution to this. In fact, I am proud of my solution, because it was tricky to think up. But it is not, by any stretch of the imagination, a good solution.

It turns out that the Unicode character [Combining Grapheme Joiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Grapheme_Joiner) is effectively a no-op in Vim. It produces no glyph, and takes up no width. It is the only such character that I have discovered. So what I do is, I surreptitiously edit the line in question to be

```
Who left the<CGJ> dead mouse in the fridge?
```

and then define a rule

```
syn match ThisMagicWord "the<CGJ>"
```

I will additionally trigger on `BufWritePre` and `BufWritePost` to strip the CGJs out of the file on disk.

**iii. The Questions**

1. Is there a no-op character in Vim (or a way to produce one) other than CGJ? Ideally a non-combining character, since `the<CGJ>` will not match a search for `/the`, due to the way Vim regexes handle combining characters.
2. Is there a better way to get at the behavior that I want?

Comment: **Why** do you need this movable single-instance highlight?! What's the reason / use case behind it?

Comment: @IngoKarkat Just to irritate you, Ingo :p. Actually, I'm using highlighting information from an external program that outputs offset ranges. It's too expensive to run repeatedly (>30 sec run time) so I need the results to persist for awhile as the user edits.

Comment: But I can imagine other uses too -- actually a lot of them (marking syntactic elements for emphasis, color coding variables to remember them better, semi-rich text formatting).

Answer (score 2):

You're right that there's currently no good way to mark static matches and keep them up-to-date when edits are done nearby. My approach would have been worse than your kludge: Include the line / column information in the match (via the `\%l` and `\%v` special atoms), and attempting to update those with a combination of marks (works for line changes) and intra-line custom diffing.

Though your use of special Unicode characters is clever, it's (as you admit) a hack. I've asked you for uses in the comments, and am still not completely satisfied / convinced. If you can come up with good, real use cases and current pain points, please direct them to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) (best with a functional draft patch attached). The functionality to keep track of such text is basically there (in the Vim internals), it's just not yet tracked and exposed to users / Vimscript. Though Vim development has been (often frustratingly) slow, with a compelling argument on your side, new functionality can and does happen.

Comment: Thank you, this is useful information. Perhaps this is not a generally useful feature, but in my case I really can't imagine how else I'd do it... So, I'm going to take a look at the Vim source and see how painful it would be to add this...

Comment: It seems [this has been discussed before](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/No-way-to-color-region-s-of-text-highlighter-mode-td1199612.html). The function `mark_col_adjust()` in fact seems to be just the thing; it just isn't called from very many places. This may not be so bad.

Answer (score 0):

How about using marks?

Move the cursor to the word you want, set a lowercase letter mark (e.g. `mz`), then add highlighting for the word like `\%'zthe`

Comment: Marks don't move with in-line edits (they move with line edits, but that's not good enough).